# How does icomparer implementing class decide sorting order on the array items?

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparable, icomparer

How does the return value of IComparer.Compare function decide the order of sorting operation? What is the significance of return values in deciding the sorting order? How does the flow of Array.Sort() happen?

For example, :

```
int[] ii = new int[3] { 8,1,4};
Array.Sort(ii, new myComp1());
```

Is there any way to understand the flow of the sorting operation. I mean if I want to decide a specific order on sorting, then how should i write if-else conditions or return values?

```
    class myComp1 : IComparer<int>
    {
            public int Compare(int x, int y)
            {
                if (x == y)
                    return 1;
                else if (x > y)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
```

For example in the code given below, I don't get the significance of the return values of comparer function whether it is going to make it ascending order or descending order or some random order. MSDN doesn't explain it very clearly.

Any help.

I would also like to understand: does Array.Sort() in below code compares 8 and 1 first, then 1 and 4, then 1 and 8? Is there any flow to this execution so that as a programmer I can figure it out before writing the actual code?
Thanks.

```
int[] kk = new int[3] { 8,1,4};
Array.Sort(kk, new myComp2());
```

```
    class myComp2 : IComparer<int>
    {
            public int Compare(int x, int y)
            {
                int res = 0;
                if (x == y)
                    return 1;
                else if (x > y)
                    return 2;
                else
                    return 3;
                return res;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seem like you are asking to explain what "less" means ("If less than 0, x is less than y") and how multiple sorting algorithms compare items (note that you probably already checked that [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8) uses 3 different sorting algorithms - insertion, heap and quick sorts). If that the case it feels the question is a bit too broad for SO...

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. I know the sorting algorithms. My question is not about the sorting algorithm. It is mainly about the return values. For example, myComp2 is not return -1,1 or 0 like myComp1, so is it even going to sort the array? What's the importance of return value here? To put it in other words: how do i know myComp1 is currently ascending or descending? Once I know, let's say ascending, how do I explain switching x to y will make the results of myComp1 descending? Thanks

Comment: I would also like to add to make my question clearer. What if myComp1 doesn't compare x and y, instead it compares x with some constant value. In that case, can i  figure out what result I should expect after calling Array.Sort().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.Sort` or any other `.Sort` variations in .NET sort items in ascending order.

When you implement your comparer, the meaning of the result is very simple:

- less than 0: `x` less than `y`
- greater than 0: `x` greater than `y`
- equals 0: `x` equals `y`
- comparison operation must be transitive, e.g. 1 ≤ 4 ≤ 8.

The order of comparing items in a set depends on a [sorting algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/), so no specific order of `Compare` calls is guaranteed.

Having `IComparer<>` is a good abstraction, and can be useful in other scenarios, not for sorting only.

If you want any specific order of items, you can either define your rules of comparer that preserves transitivity or perhaps not using `.Sort`.

---

UPDATE

As a programmer, you should think:

```cs
public int Compare(int x, int y)
{
  // OPTION 1
  if (x < y)
    return -1; // X is less than Y, place X before Y - acsending order
  ...

  // OPTION 2   
  if (x < y)
    return 1;  // X is less than Y, place X after Y - descending order
  ...

  return 0; // keep order of X and Y if possible (stable comparison only)
}
```

---

UPDATE 2

OK, imagine we have a comparer defined like this:

```cs
interface IComparer<T>
{
  SortPlacement Compare(T x, T y);
}
```

Where `SortPlacement` is defined like this:

```cs
enum SortPlacement
{
  Try_To_Keep_Same_Order_Of_X_and_Y = 0,
  Place_X_Before_Y_Ascending_Order = -1, // or any negative number
  Place_X_After_Y_Descending_Order = 1, // or any positive number
}
```

When you implement you comparer you are super clear:

```cs
public SortPlacement Compare(int x, int y)
{
  // OPTION 1
  if (x < y)
    return SortPlacement.Place_X_Before_Y_Ascending_Order;
  ...

  // OPTION 2   
  if (x < y)
    return SortPlacement.Place_X_After_Y_Descending_Order;
  ...

  // OPTION 3
  return SortPlacement.Try_To_Keep_Same_Order_Of_X_and_Y;
}
```

Now forget about silly enumertion type and replace it with integer numbers - that is a simple convention.

Comment: I got this part from MSDN too, but when we just say x and y, how do we know it is ascending or descending order? I mean the array is 8,1,4 and the comparer has two parameters x and y, but how to understand if I use the logic in your answer, it is going to be ascending or descending order. Thanks.

Comment: @psin It is up to the comparer (e.g. `myComp2`) whether it is ascending or descending.

Comment: @psin you said that you know what "less" means... Sorting in ascending order is when previous element is *less* then next...

Comment: please see the update: `-1` means `place before`, `1` means `place after`, and `0` means `keep order if possible` (stable comparer)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so which one is previous item here. Is it x or is it y? My question is not about sorting algorithm, is "return 1" for ascending order. If yes, then why?

Comment: @SergeSemenov it is actually very common and convenient to return other values - the easiest implementation of `Compare` for numbers is `return x - y;` (indeed it is confusing and likely will be randomly tweaked to `return y - x;` to fix sorting order...

Comment: `"return 1" for ascending order.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=netframework-4.8#returns  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#returns @psin

Comment: @psin "less than 0: x less than y" - resulting array will have values sorted in such a way that `Compare(a[i], a[i+1]) <= 0` - meaning a[i] *less then* a[i+1] for ascending order (obviously sensible comparison would do `Compare(a[i+1], a[i]) >= 0` in the same case).

Comment: @psin, `"return 1" for ascending order. If yes, then why?`. How else would you implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `Compare` method is used by the sorting algorithm to determine which of the two numbers should come before the other when sorting them.

Given this signature: `public int Compare(int x, int y)`

The return values mean:

- `returnValue < 0` : `x < y`
- `returnValue == 0` : `x == y`
- `returnValue > 0` : `x > y`

So if the method returns `0`, the numbers are considered equal (and their order won't change). If it returns `-1`, then the first number should come *before* the second number. And if it returns `1`, then the first number should come *after* the second number.

Now, since you've changed the definition in your `Compare` method, you will get a different order of items than one would typically expect, but that's the whole point of allowing a custom comparer - it leaves the decision making about "which comes first" to you.

However, since the return value is really only evaluated as `0`, `less than zero`, or `greater than zero`, in your second sample, since you always return a value greater than zero, the order will be unknown (it will depend on the algorithm used). I say this because when I tested it with `{1, 5, 3}` it reversed them, but when I used `{1, 5, 3, 4, 8}`, the order didn't change.

Note that, since all your cases in `comp2` return a value greater than zero, it could be rewritten:

```
public int Compare(int x, int y) { return 1; }
```

Also, the source code for [`Array.Sort`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,d076876f5fbf4eec) is online if you want to see the sorting algorithm use, but it seems like you're more interested in what

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am repeating my reply to another user.  I will put it in different way. Comparer(int x, int y) with the implementation of your answer and Compare(int y, int x) with the implementation of your answer: which will give ascending order and why?

Comment: You mentioned you are familiar with sorting algorithms, so you know they do a comparison between only two items at a time, right? When the algorthm does this comparison, it passes the items to the compare method and then decides if they should be swapped or not depending on the return value.

Comment: if I compare x and y and return some number (in this case 1), it means x > y. But does it mean the sorted result will be (x, y) or will it be (y,x)?

Comment: Given `{x, y}`, a sorting algorithm will say *"if `x` is greater than `y`, then swap them"*. So if your `Compare` method returns a value greater than zero, you will end up with `{y, x}`

Comment: Actually, after some testing, it seems hard to determine what the sort order will be if you always return a value greater than one. Using different samples, I got different results. I've updated the answer to reflect that.